# using array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST); to prevent sql injections alternatives

Tags: php, sql

So I have several questions that involve the same topic.

1. how do I use correctly  `array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);` to clean input,  I'm new to sql injection security and  don'nt quite understand how this would work, but seems much cleaner than having to apply `mysql_real_escape_string` to each  `$_POST[]`.
2. I know its better to secure from all sides  but if the information is comming from an input, wouldn't it be easier to block  certain characters to be typed, for intance `"= ","/","\" "is_admin", etc,` using javascript/jquery to prevent these comands to go through into databases ?

Comment: You can never guarantee that the request you receive on the server has actually come from your form.... hackers trying to inject malevolent SQL don't tend to use browsers, so you should always validate on the server

Comment: Also, it should be perfectly valid to have quote characters in your inputs (A surname of `O'Brian` is entirely legitimate) and the `'` needs to be escaped, not rejected

Comment: use PDO with bind parameters